# How to use Flex-box to responsive element layout?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

i have a code with a container and 2 columns, one have 1/3 of total size and other 2/3.
I resize container to 1024px of width and center element using flex properties, but i lose responsive layout.

Can I have a container on flex-box model with 1024px of width and centered, with 2 child columns, one with 1/3 of total size and other with 2/3, and still responsive? I need some code of example. my code is:

```
<HEAD>
        <STYLE>
            body {
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -moz-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: -webkit-flex;
                display: flex;

                -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
            }

            header {
                order:1;
            }

            section{
                flex: 3 auto;
                order: 1;
            }

            aside {
                flex: 1 auto;
                order: 2;
            }
            footer{
                order: 3;
            }

            #main{
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -moz-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: -webkit-flex;
                display: flex;

                order: 2;
                -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
            }

            #iSearch{
                width:100%;
            }
        </STYLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <header style="background-color:blue;">
            <input id="iSearch" type="search" placeholder="search" />
        </header>
        <div id="main">
            <section style="background-color:red;">
                ARTICLES
            </section>
            <aside style="background-color:green;">
            MENU LATERAL
            </aside>
        </div>
        <footer style="background-color:yellow;">
            copyright 2014
        </footer>
    </BODY>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem with this code on container style:

max-width:1000px;
margin:auto;

thanks guys.